# Routing to a component and subscribing in the same component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Album component which has a series of images displayed. When the user clicks on an image, a method is called which emits a BehaviorSubject (using next) and routes to another component:

Album component html:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li *ngFor="let album of albums">
        <img class="album-cover" [src]="album.albumCoverPhotoUrl" alt="album.name" (click)="onAlbumSelect(album)">
        <p class="album-name">{{ album.name }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Album component.ts:

```
onAlbumSelect(album: Album) {
    this.router.navigate(['gallery-list']);
    this.albumsService.fromAlbum.next(album);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.albumsService.fromAlbum.next(null);
    }, 100);

  }
```

In my gallery list component (the component I navigate to above), I subscribe to the BehaviorSubject and filter an array of images using the album name that I get from the emitted data:

```
ngOnInit() {  

   this.albumSub = this.albumsService.fromAlbum.subscribe(album => {

      this.selectedAlbum = album;

      if(this.selectedAlbum) {
        this.galleryList = this.images.filter(e => e.album === this.selectedAlbum.name);
      }  
}
```

I am using a behavior subject as previously I used a subject instead but this didn't work as I believe the subject was being emitted before the subscription was initialized on the gallery-list component (therefore it was missing the data emitted from the subject).

As you can see from the onAlbumSelect method from within the Album component, I am using a setTimeout method to emit a null value to reset the behviorSubject value so that it doesn't affect other parts of my code (the gallery-list component is also used to display a full list of images rather than just images from 1 album, I have left this part of the code out to as I didn't feel it was necessary to include it).

This feels somewhat 'hacky' and I am just wondering if anyone can think of a better way to approach this?

I would assume that emitting a subject, routing to a component and subscribing to the subject from within the component you are routing to is something that is done frequently in Angular apps so is there a way of doing this using just a subject (rather than a behaviorSubject) but ensuring the subscription is setup before the value is emitted? Sorry for the long post!

Comment: Indeed, this is not a good approach, since even with your timeout, you wouldn't be sure the subscription occurs before the timeout... What about using route params (giving the album id, or something like this) ?

Comment: @Random thanks for your response. Yes this was going to be my next move but I just wondered if anyone had come across this issue before as I would assume that emitting a subject, routing to a component and subscribing to the subject from within the component you are routing to is something that is done frequently in Angular apps? I did find another question asked which suggested using a behavior subject but this comes with it's own set of problems! (As outlined above)

Comment: Actually, what is difficult to do is sending a "one time event" to a component which does not exist yet. BehaviorSubject are made to store a value, and makes any subscribe to be notified if the value change. A Subject is used to send an event to a living component. What could be done is using a behavior subject, but the component reading the value would send the "null value" once he read it. But once again, that would be a workaround and does not seem clean. Routing params would be a good try for your need.